# bash: .~/.bash_profile: No such file or directory

Tags: bash

After typing the command

```
$ cd onos
$ cat << EOF >> ~/.bash_profile
export ONOS_ROOT="`pwd`"
source $ONOS_ROOT/tools/dev/bash_profile
EOF

$ .~/.bash_profile
```

I get an error

```
bash: .~/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
```

Comment: This question has been answered in:
[. ~/.bash_profile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061311/bash-profile/1061323#1061323)

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

- your main problem is pretty simple;  you need a whitespace between `.` the `source`-d filename:

  ```
  . ~/.bash_profile
  ```
- second issue you overlooked is that the variable expansions inside the here doc (`<<`) would happen in this shell i.e. the variables won't be preserved in `~/.bash_profile`. So, `ONOS_ROOT` in your example, would be set and expanded to the `$PWD`. You need to use any form of escaping on the *End of File* marker to keep the variable from expansing inside here doc:

  ```
  $ cat <<"EOF" >> ~/.bash_profile
  ...
  EOF

  $ cat <<'EOF' >> ~/.bash_profile
  ...
  EOF

  $ cat <<\EOF >> ~/.bash_profile
  ...
  EOF
  ```

  any one of the above would do.

Comment: I entered the command :   cat <<\EOF>> ~/.bash_profile
> export ONOS_ROOT=" pwd "
> source $ONOS_ROOT/tools/dev/bash_profile
> EOF
and the error was   $ . ~/.bash_profile
bash: /tools/dev/bash_profile: No such file or directory
bash: pwd/tools/dev/bash_profile: No such file or directory
bash: pwd/tools/dev/bash_profile: No such file or directory
bash: pwd/tools/dev/bash_profile: No such file or directory
bash: source: /bin/pwd: cannot execute binary file

Comment: @pranav You have run it wrong. I've edited to clarify further; please check the edits.