# . ~/.bash_profile

Tags: bash

After execution of the command

```
$ cd onos
$ cat << EOF >> ~/.bash_profile
export ONOS_ROOT="`pwd`"
source $ONOS_ROOT/tools/dev/bash_profile
EOF
$ . ~/.bash_profile
```

I am getting an error

```
bash: /tools/dev/bash_profile: No such file or directory
bash: pwd/tools/dev/bash_profile: No such file or directory
bash: pwd/tools/dev/bash_profile: No such file or directory
bash: pwd/tools/dev/bash_profile: No such file or directory
bash: source: /bin/pwd: cannot execute binary file
bash: source: /bin/pwd: cannot execute binary file
bash: source: /bin/pwd: cannot execute binary file
bash: source: /bin/pwd: cannot execute binary file
bash: source: /bin/pwd: cannot execute binary file
bash: source: /bin/pwd: cannot execute binary file
bash: /tools/dev/bash_profile: No such file or directory
bash: source: /bin/pwd: cannot execute binary file
bash: source: /bin/pwd: cannot execute binary file
bash: pwd/tools/dev/bash_profile: No such file or directory
bash: source: /bin/pwd: cannot execute binary file
```

The content of ~/.bash_profile is

```
export ONOS_ROOT="pwd"
source /tools/dev/bash_profile
export ONOS_ROOT="pwd"
source $ONOS_ROOT/tools/dev/bash_profile
export ONOS_ROOT="pwd"
source $ONOS_ROOT/tools/dev/bash_profile
export ONOS_ROOT="pwd"
source $ONOS_ROOT/tools/dev/bash_profile
export ONOS_ROOT=" pwd "
source $ONOS_ROOT/tools/dev/bash_profile
export ONOS_ROOT=" pwd "
source $ONOS_ROOT/tools/dev/bash_profile
export ONOS_ROOT=" pwd "
source $ONOS_ROOT/tools/dev/bash_profile
export ONOS_ROOT=" pwd "
source $ONOS_ROOT/tools/dev/bash_profile
export ONOS_ROOT=" pwd "
source $ONOS_ROOT/tools/dev/bash_profile
export ONOS_ROOT=" pwd "
source $ONOS_ROOT/tools/dev/bash_profile
export ONOS_ROOT=" pwd "
source /tools/dev/bash_profile
export ONOS_ROOT=" pwd "
source $ONOS_ROOT/tools/dev/bash_profile
export ONOS_ROOT=" pwd "
source  pwd /tools/dev/bash_profile
export ONOS_ROOT="pwd"
source $ONOS_ROOT/tools/dev/bash_profile
export ONOS_ROOT=" pwd "
source $ONOS_ROOT/tools/dev/bash_profile
```

Answer (score 2):

This edit to your `.bash_profile` is incorrect, because the `$ONOS_ROOT` variable is expanded by your here-document (`<<EOF`), so it's not kept verbatim, which I believe is what you wanted:

```
$ cd onos
$ cat << EOF >> ~/.bash_profile
export ONOS_ROOT="`pwd`"
source $ONOS_ROOT/tools/dev/bash_profile
EOF
```

The variable is most likely empty, so it expands to nothing, which explains the `source /tools/dev/bash_profile` line you have in your `.bash_profile` after running this command.

My recommendation is to use something like this instead:

```
$ cd onos
$ { echo "export ONOS_ROOT=`pwd`";
    echo 'source $ONOS_ROOT/tools/dev/bash_profile'; } >>~/.bash_profile
```

Which uses two separate echos, the first using double quotes in order to expand the `pwd` command output, the second using single quotes to prevent expanding the `$ONOS_ROOT` variable reference you want to preserve.

This command will still append lines more than once, if you run it repeatedly. So, perhaps, you want to add a check of whether the edit was already performed, in which case you would skip appending:

```
$ cd onos
$ grep -qw ONOS_ROOT ~/.bash_profile || {
    echo "export ONOS_ROOT=`pwd`";
    echo 'source $ONOS_ROOT/tools/dev/bash_profile';
  } >>~/.bash_profile
```

---

Also, this command:

```
$ . ~/.bash_profile
```

It can cause issues as well, since `.bash_profile` is typically supposed to be sourced only once... You're likely to end up with spurious repeated entries in your `$PATH` at least, which might cause unexpected issues... Best would be to log out and log in again, or to start a new terminal session (assuming your terminal spawns login shells) to have these new settings take effect.